# Is there any difference between these two ways of declaring extension methods in Dart?

Tags: dart

I've found the following extensions:

```dart
extension ComparableBiggerExtension<T extends Comparable<T>> on T {
  bool operator >(T other) => compareTo(other) > 0;
}
```

And:

```dart
extension ComparableBiggerExtension<T> on Comparable<T> {
  bool operator >(T other) => compareTo(other) > 0;
}
```

---

Both declare the operator `>` for the type `Comparable<T>` where `T` is a generic. But my question is: is there any difference besides the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not entirely the same, consider the following program

```dart
void main() {
  print(A() > "example");
}

class A implements Comparable<String> {
  @override
  int compareTo(String other) => 0;
}

extension ComparableBiggerExtension<T extends Comparable<T>> on T {
  bool operator >(T other) => compareTo(other) > 0;
}
```

which produces the following error

```
: Error: The operator '>' isn't defined for the class 'A'.
extensions.dart:2
- 'A' is from 'bin/extensions.dart'.
extensions.dart:1
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '>' operator.
  print(A() > "example");
            ^
```

The reason this doesn't work is because `A` extends from `Comparable<String>` rather than `Comparable<A>`.

However when using the second extension definition

```dart
void main() {
  print(A() > "example");
}

class A implements Comparable<String> {
  @override
  int compareTo(String other) => 0;
}

extension ComparableBiggerExtension2<T> on Comparable<T> {
  bool operator >(T other) => compareTo(other) > 0;
}
```

the program successfuly runs with the following output

```
false
```

The above extension works fine given that `A` is a `Comparable<String>`.

In other words the first definition only work on types that compare against themselves, while the second definition work on `Comparable` types regardless if they compare against themselves or some other type.